Disable python package imports depending on available libraries
In my python-based project I am using several functions from PySide6. These functions require libraries such as libGl.so and libglib.so. This is not a problem when using the package as a standalone-package.
When packaging it into a docker-image and using python:3.12 or similar base images, I however have to add
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libegl-dev -y

during build-time, to add these packages. As I try to keep my resulting image as small as possible, I would like to avoid this step.
Is there any way of using something similar as (e.g.) preprocessor routines in C++, to selectively disable imports depending on availability of libraries? I am aware of that this might also disable other functions, but for the purpose of this question this is not relevant, as I don't use these functions anyway in the volume-context.

In a Docker context, you can usually use a multi-stage build to avoid needing a large ...-dev package in your final image.  The apt-get install --no-install-recommends option can also help avoiding OS packages you don't really need.  Do these bring the image size down enough that you don't need conditional code tricks?

Is the problem that the import fails, or that functions defined by a successful import fail when called?

@DavidMaze: PySide6 is (unfortunately) not only a dev-inclusion, but also a regular package, thus I can't go that way, and therefore the idea of using something similar as pre-processor directives.

@chepner The import fails because a library could not be found

"This is not a problem when using the package as a standalone-package." I'm not sure what this means: are you just saying the necessary packages are available outside your docker image? It seems like you already need libGl.so for your code, so putting them in your Docker image is the only option. Ignoring the ImportError, as suggested by other answers, doesn't help you if your code continues to try to use the module.

You could use following structure, to import only available packages:
try:
    import some_module
except ImportError:
    some_module = None

if some_module:
    pass
else:
    pass


How would I treat functions which have parameters which can be used depending on the module? In C++ I could disable these with preprocessor directives, too, but I'm not sure if that would work here.

Could you please provide example of these functions with different states, to make my answer 100% accurate

This assumes that trying to import the package will fail in the face of missing dependencies, rather than some function defined by the package failing when actually called.
